quinn or rustls cetificate error: UnknownIssuer
Rust version: 1.78 stable
OS: Windows 11
OpenSSL: 3.0.11 19
I try use quinn to made a simple app to build a QUIC connection, here is code below:
// Server code

use std::{fs, sync::Arc};
use quinn::crypto::rustls::QuicServerConfig;
use rustls::pki_types::{CertificateDer, PrivateKeyDer, PrivatePkcs8KeyDer};

pub const ALPN_QUIC_HTTP: &[&[u8]] = &[b"hq-29"];

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    dotenv::dotenv()?;
    env_logger::init();

    rustls::crypto::ring::default_provider()
        .install_default()
        .expect("Failed to install rustls crypto provider");
    let cert = fs::read("C:/Projects/certificates/certificate.der")?;
    let key = fs::read("C:/Projects/certificates/private_key.der")?;

    let cert = CertificateDer::from(cert);
    let key = PrivateKeyDer::Pkcs8(PrivatePkcs8KeyDer::try_from(key)?);

    let mut server_config = rustls::ServerConfig::builder()
        .with_no_client_auth()
        .with_single_cert(vec![cert], key)?;
    server_config.alpn_protocols = ALPN_QUIC_HTTP.iter().map(|&x| x.into()).collect();
    let server_config =
        quinn::ServerConfig::with_crypto(Arc::new(QuicServerConfig::try_from(server_config)?));

    let endpoint = quinn::Endpoint::server(server_config, "127.0.0.1:8898".parse()?)?;

    let mut b = [0u8; 1024];

    while let Some(conn) = endpoint.accept().await {
        let (mut send, mut recv) = conn.await?.open_bi().await?;

        while let Ok(_) = recv.read(&mut b).await {
            send.write_all(&mut b).await?;
        }
    }

    Ok(())
}


// Client

use std::fs;
use std::sync::Arc;
use quinn::crypto::rustls::QuicClientConfig;
use rustls::pki_types::CertificateDer;

pub const ALPN_QUIC_HTTP: &[&[u8]] = &[b"hq-29"];

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    dotenv::dotenv()?;
    env_logger::init();

    rustls::crypto::ring::default_provider()
        .install_default()
        .expect("Failed to install rustls crypto provider");
    // let cert = fs::read("C:/Projects/certificates/server.crt")?;

    // let cert = CertificateDer::from(cert);

    let mut roots = rustls::RootCertStore::empty();
    roots.add(CertificateDer::from(fs::read(
        "C:/Projects/certificates/certificate.der",
    )?))?;
    let mut client_crypto = rustls::ClientConfig::builder()
        .with_root_certificates(roots)
        .with_no_client_auth();

    client_crypto.alpn_protocols = ALPN_QUIC_HTTP.iter().map(|&x| x.into()).collect();
    let client_config =
        quinn::ClientConfig::new(Arc::new(QuicClientConfig::try_from(client_crypto)?));
    let mut endpoint = quinn::Endpoint::client("0.0.0.0:0".parse()?)?;
    endpoint.set_default_client_config(client_config);

    let conn = endpoint
        .connect("127.0.0.1:8898".parse()?, "localhost")?
        .await?;

    Ok(())
}

Very simple code, please note the certificating part of code, the key and the certificate files: private_key.der and certificate.der, is self-signed certificate by OpenSSL.
But when I run server code and client code it would appears error:
Error: ConnectionClosed(ConnectionClose { error_code: Code::crypto(30), frame_type: None, reason: b"invalid peer certificate: UnknownIssuer" })
error: process didn't exit successfully: `C:\Projects\friends\target\debug\server.exe` (exit code: 1)

I thought maybe I signed wrong, I did that following this post: How to Create Self-Signed Certificates using OpenSSL, here are some commands I used:
openssl req -x509             -sha256 -days 356             -nodes             -newkey rsa:2048             -subj "/CN=Localhost/C=US/L=San Fransisco"             -keyout rootCA.key -out rootCA.crt

openssl genrsa -out server_key.pem 2048

And wrote the content to the csr.conf:
[ req ]
default_bits = 2048
prompt = no
default_md = sha256
req_extensions = req_ext
distinguished_name = dn

[ dn ]
C = US
ST = California
L = San Fransisco
O = MLopsHub
OU = MlopsHub Dev
CN = Localhost

[ req_ext ]
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[ alt_names ]
DNS.1 = localhost
IP.1 = 127.0.0.1

And go ahead:
openssl req -new -key server_key.pem -out server.csr -config csr.conf

And wrote the content to the cert.conf:
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = localhost

And go ahead:
openssl x509 -req     -in server.csr     -CA rootCA.crt -CAkey rootCA.key     -CAcreateserial -out server_crt.pem     -days 365     -sha256 -extfile cert.conf

At the end convert server_key.pem to private_key.der, and convert server_cert.pem to certificate.der
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -outform DER -in server_key.pem -out private_key.der -nocrypt

openssl x509 -outform der -in server_cert.pem -out certificate.der


And the CA ca_cert.crt, I had been trust it on the certmgr

I have tried hard and don't know why it was not work, anyone has idea?

Those openssl commands generate the server (EE) cert with no extensions and thus X.509 version 1. Version 3 added extensions in 1997, and today many people -- and programs -- consider anything that is not v3 obsolete, but I have no knowledge about the rust library(s?) you are using. If it(?) does, and you are using OpenSSL 3.0.0 (from 2021) or higher with a config file based on upstream at least for the req_extensions item and the [v3_req] section, then adding -copy_extensions copy to the x509 -req -CA* command will put reasonable extensions in the server cert and make it v3.
